# Non-binary inference rules

Tags: logic

Inference rules in classical logic are, AFAIK, *binary* in that they show the relationship between the *two* premises and the conclusion. One can also devise non-binary rules that can be reduced or converted to a sequence of binary inference steps, much as ternary addition operator $+(a,b,c)$ can be written as two consecutive binary additions $+(+(a,b),c)$.

Is there any inference rule that is NOT binary and is not reducible to binary ones? Is there a reference to read more about this?

Comment: Have a look at nonclassical logic; specifically, [many-valued logics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-valued_logic).

Comment: @Shaun What about classical logics? Is there a proof that no non-binary inference rule exists? Is there a reference discussing this issue?

Comment: But neither arithmetic nor logical operators are [inference rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference#Table:_Rules_of_Inference), each of which enables us to derive a conclusion from (typically one to three) premises.

Comment: @ryang I know that. I just wanted to give an example or metaphor, so to speak.

Comment: I see! Welcome to MSE! Hazarding a guess: disjunction elimination?

Comment: In your question you're talking about inference rules in a general way. But there are many different proof systems (natural deduction, sequent calculus, Hilbert system, deep inference, etc.), with very different styles for inference rules, and each kind of proof system can be instantiated for different logics (classical, intuitionistic, linear, modal, etc.). Do you refer to a precise set of inference rules in a precise proof system? Otherwise I guess your question is too generic.

Answer (score 1):

Inference rules of arity $\geq 3$ are sometimes necessary. I'll give the example closest to my mind:

In my paper *[Exploring the Landscape of Relational Syllogistic Logics](https://doi.org/10.1017/S1755020320000386)* (arXiv [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.00656)) with Larry Moss, we prove completeness theorems for a number of simple logics, often using systems with inference rules of arity $\geq 3$. See e.g. the rule $(\mathsf{CASES}^*)$ in Section 2.3, the schema $(\mathsf{CHAINS})$ in Section 2.4, and the rules $(\mathsf{DD})$ and $(\mathsf{DD}')$ in Section 2.5. We also show in Section 2.2 that there is no (finite) "syllogistic proof system" for the logic we call $\mathcal{L}_2$, because any complete set of "syllogistic rules" for this logic must have rules of unbounded arity!

Comment: In case of CASES*, isn't the conclusion (some a b), just one of the premises?

Comment: @Kaveh No. The way you read this rule is as follows: Suppose we have (1) a proof of (all x a), (2) a proof of (all x b), and (3) a proof of (some a b) *conditionally* on the extra hypothesis (all y (r all x)). Then we can discharge the hypothesis (all y (r all x)) and conclude (some a b) *unconditionally*. The bit about discharging hypotheses is common in natural deduction systems, but it makes this rule fail to be a "syllogistic rule" in the sense of our paper. (CHAINS), (DD), and (DD') are examples of non-binary syllogistic rules, with no discharging of hypotheses.